# How do I install Pytorch 1.3.1 with CUDA enabled

Tags: python, cuda

I have a conda environment on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

When I install Pytorch using:

```
conda install pytorch
```

and I try and run the script I need, I get the error message:

```
raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
```

From looking at forums, I see that this is because I have installed Pytorch without CUDA support.

I then tried:

```
conda install -c pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 pytorch
```

but now I get the error:

```
    from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CUDAExtension
  File "/home/username/miniconda3/envs/super_resolution/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

So it seems that these two installs are installing different versions of Pytorch(?). The first one that seemed to work was Pytorch 1.3.1.

My question: How do I install Pytorch with CUDA enabled, but ensure it is version `1.3.1` so that it works with my system?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose only from a limited selection of pre-built pytorch versions when you use the official anaconda installer at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ (and then choose the cuda option there, of course).

If you want a specific version that is not provided there anymore, you need to install it from source. See an example of how to do that (though for a Windows case, but just to start with) at [How to install pytorch (with cuda enabled for a deprecated CUDA cc 3.5 of an old gpu) FROM SOURCE using anaconda prompt on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1596115/how-to-install-pytorch-with-cuda-enabled-for-a-deprecated-cuda-cc-3-5-of-an-old).